# How to set text of all textfields and buttons in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to set text of all the edit texts and buttons of my activity to their original text. (The text that was on them at start of the activity).
There are a lot of fields and buttons so any pointer on how to do it without manually setting the text back to their original text for every single edit text and button?
Thanks

Comment: this original text you say is one unique text to every textviews?

Comment: every textview has some different text set on them and after the user changes them , and press reset I want to make the text of the textview to that original text they had before user changed them.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend a custom class from EditText with a method that will store the current text into a private member variable. In your Activity's onResume() method you would then call this method. Whenever you want to reset the EditText's text to its original text, you would then call another simple method that will set the current text to the text stored before.

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText {

private String mStoredText;

public MyEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void storeText() {
    mStoredText = getText().toString();
}

public void restoreText() {
    setText(mStoredText);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and i will still be manually setting the text to every Edit text i have?

Comment: Yea sure. You're using it just like the standard EditText. You're simply providing methods to store and restore the text. You can choose now when to store and when to restore your text programmaticaly.